# In android every .java file becomes an app on the phone!

Tags: android

I have 6 .java files under one package.In eclipse, after I export the `.apk` and install the app on the phone or if i run the app on the emulator, there are 6 applications created, one for each .java file! The java files are different screens in my app.So i can open any java file by clicking on the icon in the menu.I only want one of them to be openable through the icon in the menu. So basically, only one icon should be seen in the main menu, which upon clicking opens the first activity in the manifest file!

Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption:
You registered all your Activities in the AndroidManifest (which is right) but as intent-filter you always used

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

That intent-filter tells Android to add the Activity to the launcher. Remove those Intent-filters (except one Activity that's going to be your main entry point) and it should work.

Comment: If you rated my answer, I'm not quite sure if you used the right arrow. -1 for a solution??

Comment: Just noticed the -1 so I just added +1 for this and Deva's answer.

Answer (score 0):

What does your manifest say? It might specify that all activities are shown as seperate apps...

Comment: how does it specify that. i have separate activity tags for each .java file. 
Its the following for each activity..
'
 <activity android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
'

Answer (score 0):

Just check your AndroidManifest.xml file and modify your activity same as below code example:

```
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
                  android:label="SecondActivity">
        </activity>
```

So if you mark the above code then you can easily come to know that the below code mention that this activity is going to be act as a launcher activity.

```
 <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention the intent-filter action as MAIN and Category as Launcher only for your entry activity in your app.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
</intent-filter>.
```

Remove this for all other activities except the entry point for your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is a solution marked -1? maybe someone used the wrong arrow?